# How do you change the background on a div to an image in HTML?

Tags: html, image, background-image

I have tried a few things and cannot get anything to work: I am trying to give my div a background image. Below is some of the things I have tried and a snippet of my code. Thank you in advance!

```
<div style="background-image: url('images\storefrontday.jpg');"></div>
<div style="background: color url('images\storefrontday.jpg')"></div>
```

I have also tried to add the background in external CSS to no avail.

```
  <section class="opening">
        <div style="background: color url('images\storefrontday.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="container-fluid"> 
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark"> 
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="images\logo.webp"> The Fish House & Grill</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
```

Comment: What's the issue? What is `color`?

Comment: Those are a couple of ways to add a background image to a div on a couple different websites, but neither are working.

Comment: Can you check if the path to the images is correct?

Comment: Yes, the path is correct.

Comment: You shouldn't need `color` when you specify the `background` prop. `background: color url('images\storefrontday.jpg')`

Answer (score 0):

@pai.not.pi you were so right. I was doing "copy relative path" and pasting in the space. It was doing a back-slash instead of a forward-slash. Also, the quotes were not needed. Problem solved and a lesson learned. Thank you so much for your assistance. I hope you have an amazing week!

```
.opening{
     border-style: double;
     background-image: url(images/storefrontday.jpg);
     background-size:100% 100%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```